# Is it possible to use android:inputType with a string resource

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I'm making an android app for multiple languages.  I would like to set the inputType for an EditText view to be different based on the keyboard language.  In the XML file I've tried:

```
android:inputType="@string/xyz"
```

and in the Strings resource file string xyz would be

```
<string name="xyz">number</string>
```

I was hoping that this was a smart idea for easily changing the input type bases on language.  For example, if the language were English I would set xyz to letters, but in Japanese I would have xyz as numbers.  I was trying to avoid doing this programmatically because as soon as I start entering input filters in code much of my XML settings are ignored, even if they are not directly overridden by the new code.

I get an error though when I try to call this string resource to the inputType.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can achieve this programmatically since `inputType` can take an `integer` value. Here is the implementation it is actually so easy.

[TYPE_CLASS_TEXT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) has a constant value: **1**

[TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER) has constant value: **2**

This is the value your strings.xml (which you are going to localise):
For example:

input_type value in strings for English (text):

```
<string name="input_type">1</string>
```

input_type value in strings for Japanese (number):

```
<string name="input_type">2</string>
```

In your `Activity`, declare your `EditText` and set the `inputType` from strings.xml so it will be set according to the localisation:

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.setInputType(Integer.parseInt(getResources().
                                       getString(R.string.input_type)));
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is helpful,  definitely,  but will this still allow me to specify accepted characters for the edittext from within the xml?  I.e., android:digits.  Or will this code negate that in xml?  I would like to accept, for example, abcde only.  This works until I set input filters in code.   I'll try your code now to see.  I'm trying to figure out how to limit to specific characters in code if I cant in xml.  But the. Inputfilter is still confusing to me.

Comment: this will work only for a single attribute; for more complex, like `textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword|number` this solution will not work as it is.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this. The `android:inputType` attribute is defined as using flags that are also defined by Android. You cannot provide an arbitrary string value for this attribute, you can only use those pre-defined flags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only via XML but you have to use an `integer` and not a `string` resource:

In your value folder

```
<integer name="myInputType">12</integer> <!-- numberPassword -->
```

In your layout

```
android:inputType="@integer/myInputType"
```

The integer values are listed here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use (and override) style for your EditText (with  attrs) for each language qualificator

f.e.

```
 <style name="PinCodeInputType">
    <item name="android:inputType">numberDecimal</item>
</style>



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/code"
    style="@style/PinCodeInputType"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```